# the equation $x^2-y^2 =a^2$ changes to the form $xy=c^2$ if the co-ordinate axes rotates through an angle (keeping origin fixed)

Tags: quadratics

the equation $x^2-y^2 =a^2$ changes to the form $xy=c^2$ if the co-ordinate axes rotates through an angle

(keeping origins fixed) is

a) $ \frac \pi 2 $
b) $ - \frac \pi 2 $
c) $ \frac \pi 4 $
d) $ \frac \pi 3 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we put
$$x=\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and
$$y=\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}}$$

then

$$x^2-y^2=a^2=2XY$$
or
$$XY=(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})^2=c^2$$

But $$\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
the right answer is $ c)$.

Comment: Very fast...are you flash? :-) +1 Just it was an equilateral hyperbola.

Comment: thank you very much , i somehow understood it.